# ApplyProvisioningTemplate SharePoint Publishing Feature no response in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

We want to enable some SharePoint features during the provisioning process. In our PnP-Template there are three GUIDs of features, which have to be enabled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:Preferences Generator="OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=2.17.1708.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3751622786b357c2" />
  <pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-TEMPLATE-F207AD80A5E746C9B3F9955B844AA650">
    <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="MANDANT-SITE" Version="1">
      <pnp:Features>
        <pnp:SiteFeatures>
          <!-- Publishing Site Feature -->
          <pnp:Feature ID="f6924d36-2fa8-4f0b-b16d-06b7250180fa" />
          <pnp:Feature ID="8A4B8DE2-6FD8-41e9-923C-C7C3C00F8295" />
        </pnp:SiteFeatures>
        <pnp:WebFeatures>
          <!-- Publishing Web Feature -->
          <pnp:Feature ID="94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb" />
        </pnp:WebFeatures>
      </pnp:Features>
    </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
  </pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>
```

Sometimes this process stucks. Mostly the first feature (SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure) works well. But than the SharePoint Online does no response. I do not get any error, exception or something else.
The other features are not enabled...
When I stop the Azure WebJob (cmd-application) and start it again - all features will be enabled.

The following calls the PnP-Template:

```
        var provisioningInfo = new ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation();
        provisioningInfo.ProgressDelegate = (message, step, total) =>
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("Applying provisioning template - step {0}/{1} : {2}", step, total, message);
            Console.WriteLine("Applying provisioning template - step " + step + "/" + total + ":" + message);
***AFTER THIS Console.WriteLine NOTHING HAPPENS ANYMORE***
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Try to provisioning");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        try
        {
            UsingContext(siteRequest.Url, ctx =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try to get client context of provisioning");
                Thread.CurrentThread.RunWithCulture((int)siteRequest.Lcid, () =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Start ApplyProvisioningTemplate");
                    ctx.Site.RootWeb.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisioningTemplate.OriginalTemplate, provisioningInfo);
                    provisioningTemplate.Provision(ctx);
                    Console.WriteLine("End ApplyProvisioningTemplate");
                });
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occured while applying the provisioning template. " + ex);
            Log.Error("An error occured while applying the provisioning template.", ex);
            throw new ProvisioningTemplateException(ex.Message, ex);
        }
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? Is there a timeout, because enabling the SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure takes round about three minutes?

It would be nice to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to fix this issue, was to set an time out for the Client Context.

```
 ctx.RequestTimeout = -1;
```